# Python: how to loop over 10, then backprop, then loop over next 10

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, neural-network

I'm training a neural network and want my program to feed forward the first 10 examples, then backprop, then loop over next 10 examples and backprop and so on.

Right now I have a code that loops over my whole data set for 5 epochs, but it would be better if it looped in small batches (also for 5 epochs for example).

My question is how to make a loop, based on the one I have, so that it loops over the first 10 `i`, then does the `Net.backward(rate, mse)` bit, resets the error sum `sum_error = 0` and then loops over the next 10 `i` and so on, for the whole dataset (I have 800 examples). I don't know how to achieve that. Should I insert some kind of `i` counter, like `i = i+1`?

```
for j in range(5):
    for i, pattern in enumerate(X):
        Net.net_error(y[i], X[i])
        sum_error = sum_error + np.square(Net.net_error(y[i],X[i]))
    mse = (sum_error) / (len(X))
    print(f" # {str(j)}{mse}")
    Net.backward(rate, mse)
    sum_error = 0
```

The code that is responsible for `net_error` part:

```
def feed_forward(self, X):
    self.z1 = np.dot(X, self.input_to_hidden1_w)
    self.z1_a = self.activation(self.z1)

    self.z2 = np.dot(self.z1_a, self.hidden1_to_hidden2_w)
    self.z2_a = self.activation(self.z2)

    self.z3 = np.dot(self.z2_a, self.hidden2_to_output_w)
    self.output = self.activation(self.z3)
    return self.output

def net_error(self, y, X):
    net_error = y - self.feed_forward(X)
    return net_error
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there some specific thing you don't know how to do?

Comment: Additionally, why do you have `i` in two different `for` loops? Isn't that going to cause problems?

Comment: I have `i` in two places, so that the program takes corresponding example and output, since I have it in two matrices. It doesn't cause problems, everything works ok. My question is how to make a loop, based on the one I have, so that it loops over the first 10 `i`, then does the `Net.backward(rate, mse)` bit, resets the error sum `sum_error = 0` and then loops over the next 10 `i` and so on, for the whole dataset (I have 1000 examples).

Comment: are you sure that "everything works ok" with that code, looks very likely to be doing the wrong thing to me.  at the moment you're getting the `net_error` of the diagonal `len(X)` times

Comment: @Agness_K The `i` you use in `Net.net_error(y[i], X[i])` is always going to be the `i` corresponding to `enumerate(y)`.

Comment: I think it works ok at the moment, as a code, however as a network it is rubbish, due to the batch issue. I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, so let me paste the code that is used in `net_error` in the question description.

Comment: @Agness_K try doing `print(i, y[i], X[i], Net.net_error(y[i], X[i]))` inside your `for` loops, might help you understand what's going on

Comment: @SamMason I did that,let me paste one of the results I got: `612 [[0.66464702]] [[0.62178425 0.6421415  0.67966271 0.69283505 0.70880152 0.68105769
  0.68345925 0.67665483 0.68546055 0.68345925 0.68305899 0.67985691
  0.65023765 0.66744884]] [[0.16210393]]`. I think it is ok regarding the correct example and correct output values. I had similar `print` part inserted before, so I'm pretty confident that it gives me the right values.

Comment: look at how many times this is getting printed for each of your `f" # {str(j)}{mse}"` prints.  I guess it's 1000 times (i.e. `len(X)`) too many

Comment: @SamMason Ok, I get what you meant! I was mislead by the fact that it was always corresponding values. This was of great help, thank you! I corrected my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as to your original question, I think you might want to do something like:

```
num_epochs = 5
batch_size = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    perm_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))

    for ix in range(0, len(perm_idx), batch_size):
        batch_indicies = perm_idx[ix:ix+batch_size]

        sum_error = 0
        for i in batch_indicies:
            sum_error += np.square(Net.net_error(y[i], X[i]))

        Net.backward(rate, sum_error / len(X))
```

note that I'm using `permutation` to get random subsets of the data in each batch, which might help with biases